# Regedit expression special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How would I add an regedit expression that will trap for special characters like spaces?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>
<span class="required">*
</span>
Code:
</label>
<input class="form-control glValidate" name="txtCode" id="txtCode" />
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "trap for special characters"? Are you wanting to return them in a group, determine if they exist, break on them? What do you consider a special character (spaces aren't usually considered special characters)?

Comment: @RonBeyer I was thinking just to break on them

Comment: I was thinking this would work but it is not <input class="form-control glValidate" pattern="^\s-^!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|" title="" name="txtCode" id="txtCode" />

Comment: hmm, your sample expression contains double quotes.
you may want to escape them with &quot; 

 `pattern="^\s-^!@#$%^&*(),.?&quot;:{}|"`